# Pandas: Replace zero and NAN values with column Mean depending on product type

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I want to replace zero and NAN values with column Mean, however, i want the code to categorize the mean in relation to product type (A B or C)

so to summarize,I have a pandas dataframe with a total of 4 columns. One of the columns specifies one of 3 product types: A, B and C.

Each row has 3 measurement columns. I want to replace the 0 and NAN values for each column, with the column mean in respect to the product type. Table as below:

Hence i want to write a syntax that will allow the software to calculate the following:

product A Mean  for each of the column measurements 1,2 and 3

product B Mean  for each of the column measurements 1,2 and 3

product C Mean  for each of the column measurements 1,2 and 3

and then replace the nan and zero column values with the respective calculated mean.
[image]

for such an operation, we can use the following line of code:

```
df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
```

However this assumes mean applies for all values in the column and not in respect to categories defined in another column (here being product type categories A,B and C)

Much appreciate your help on this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `transform` with `groupby`

```
df.fillna(df.groupby('PRODUCT TYPE').transform('mean'), inplace=True)
```